# SQL Server Job running for prolonged duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I have a `SQL Server 2008` scheduled job. The job is meant for `fragmentation` of `table data`.  I am using below `SQL queries` (*on multiple tables*):

```
   //To fetch the fragmentation related information
   DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('Table','Index') WITH FAST, TABLERESULTS

   //For index defragmentation
   DBCC INDEXDEFRAG ('DB','Table','Index')
```

Typically, it used to run for under 3-4 minutes. However, of late, it has been running over 4-5 hours. I am not sure how to proceed to find the root cause of this behavior.

Any leads would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

**Edited on 26-05-2016 13:52 IST**
I had been contemplating using *DBCC SHRINKDATABASE* to improve the issue at hand. Any suggestions?

**Edited on 26-05-2016 15:24 IST**
I had enabled trace and logging through Performance Monitor (perfmon.msc) on the production during the job run. However, I could not make any sense out of generated files.

Comment: Data growth? Parallel work running?

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Autogrowth by 10%. Max. Size (Data): Unlimited,
Max. Size (Log) : Limited to 1TB.
No perfomance-hitting jobs are run parallel.

Comment: It's nothing to do with autogrowth here, I mean: aren't your data and indexes currently much bigger than before?

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Sorry I misinterpret your question. Yes, data is larger than before; I am not sure how to gauge the indexes.

Comment: There are many scripts in internet about measuring different things in mssql, try searching for it. And watch performance counters when your task is executed. If your data is much larger then before - may be current execution time is just fine. Anyway without exact numbers (size, counters and so on) there is nothing to suggest.